# /users card tags keeps changing - is there a reason?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-completed, users-page

While I realize this area is under development, why does the order keep changing?

The tags themselves do not change - implying that there is some method to madness, but if there is a method, say "top 3 tags by votes/answers+questions" (or some such), one would expect a certain ordering to the presentation to follow the same selection criteria.

Just clicking on the same period over and over and over changes the order of the tags.

Could it be something as simple as a missing ORDER BY clause somewhere?

#### EDIT - fixed the poor quality bug report

https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=quarter

Click on "Quarter" over and over and over..

Comment: Please stop clicking that button.  You are making it slow for everybody else.

Comment: I can't make it out if you meant `:)`, so I apologize for slowing down your internets. I owe you some tubes

Comment: we can't reproduce this -- where are you seeing non-deterministic tag orderings on the user page? Can you provide a URL?

Comment: @Jeff - link added

Comment: I observed the same. And indeed only on Quarter.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this, keep them coming :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just checked in a fix,

Will order this deterministically from now on, (num votes -> then tag name).

Comment: to be deployed today

Comment: +1 for making it determinate, but `alphabetically` - really? I guess you've lost context of the vote/rep counts by then.

Comment: @cyperkiwi I can maintain the context somehow ...  ill see if I can just tie break on names

Answer (score 2):

> While I realize this area is under development[...]

I believe that is the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm performing QA. Isn't that what good peops do? I mean, there is no BETA parallel site so this is being beta-tested in the wild right?

Comment: @Richard, I would call it beta testing.  This feature is basically brand new.

Comment: So, don't beta testing bug reports get filed in Meta? Is there another channel?

Comment: @Richard, you are in the right place.  Sorry to be confusing.  My answer was just meant to point out that the reason for the bug is probably because of the fact it's a brand new feature.